# Разный css при обновлении страницы F5

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Веб дизайн только познаю,  хотя занимаюсь им давненько,  но понимаю что это бездна знаний и вот по сути вопрос в чем.  Как сделать разный CSS при перезагрузке страницы?  Разные иконки например,  что бы разным посетителям сайта показывались разные иконки.  И при обновлении нажимая на F5 менялись стили иконок. 
???

Comment: через js или бекенд менять, рандомно или неочень ... вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: ну что бы хотя бы три разных стиля повесить. можно и рандомно. Я просто не понимаю принцип как такое сделать вообще. Мне бы пример хоть где то посмотреть

Comment: опишите конкретно на примере какого-то блока, как он выглядит, что должно меняться и как (каждый раз новое или по какому-то принципу) .... способов это сделать десятки и все они зависят от того что конкретно требуется получить в итоге.

Comment: И поясните, должны ли применятся рандомные стили для каждого необходимого элемента, или с разделением на группы? Т.е. элементам с классом, например, `.icon` "выпадают" рандомные стили из одного диапазона, а элементам с `.text` - из другого?

Comment: мы имеем кнопки с одним классом .class1 к примеру и разными id к примеру #id1 #id2 #id3 вот как сделать что бы при нажатии F5 у кнопки применялся другой #id  а класс оставался прежний?

Comment: @АлександрКазбанов вы стили через id прописываете что ли?

Comment: обычно через классы но почему то подумал что через id будет проще. в принципе можно же и несколько классов на кнопку прописать

Comment: Такое лучше делать через Бэкенд, и лучше разбить на разные CSS файлы, один общий где будут стили для всех вариантов, и несколько где будет меняться именно стилистика кнопок и всего того что вам надо менять в дизайне, и просто при генерации HTML кода указываете название файла CSS который необходимо подключить, как именно выбирать какой файл подключать это уже сами решите, рандомно или на сессию или из настроек пользователя.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На чистом **JavaScript**:

```js
var styles = ['blue', 'red', 'green']; // диапазон значений

randomStyles('class', styles); // вызываем функцию "рандомных стилей"

function randomStyles(sel, arr) { // sel - селектор, arr - диапазон значений
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName(sel), // получаем элементы с необходимым классом
    newArr = arr; // объявляем новый массив
  for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) { // перебираем все элементы с классом
    var randClass = newArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * newArr.length)]; // рандомное значение из массива
    els[i].classList.add('class-' + randClass); // добавляем элементу класс с полученным значением
    newArr.splice(newArr.indexOf(randClass), 1); // удаляем из массива подставленный класс, чтобы избежать повтора
  }
}
```

```css
.class {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.class-blue {
  background: blue;
}

.class-red {
  background: red;
}

.class-green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
```

Этот же вариант на **jQuery** (производительность ниже, но вдруг кому-то пригодится):

```js
var styles = ['blue', 'red', 'green']; // диапазон значений

randomStyles('.class', styles); // вызываем функцию "рандомных стилей"

function randomStyles(sel, arr) { // sel - селектор, arr - диапазон значений
  var els = $(sel), // получаем элементы с необходимым классом
    newArr = arr; // объявляем новый массив
  els.each(function(id) { // перебираем все элементы с классом
    var randClass = newArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * newArr.length)]; // рандомное значение из массива
    $(this).addClass('class-' + randClass); // добавляем элементу класс с полученным значением
    newArr.splice($.inArray(randClass, newArr), 1); // удаляем из массива подставленный класс, чтобы избежать повтора
  });

}
```

```css
.class {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.class-blue {
  background: blue;
}

.class-red {
  background: red;
}

.class-green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное приогромнейшее.

Comment: @АлександрКазбанов Пожалуйста